# href inside updatepanel is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'Ve used `UpdatePanel` inside `<div>` which having `<a>` with `<Eval>` inside it. 
It's working fine for `<div>` but,When i clicked on `<a>` tag  inside `<div>` it's opening like a new page. Previously it was like Pop-Up. Here's my Code

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress1" runat="server">
      <ProgressTemplate>
        <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
          <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" Width="325px" Height="250px" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loader.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." Style="border-width: 0px; position: center; padding: 50px; font-size: 36px;" />
        </div>
      </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <div class="box box-default collapsed-box" id="divThree" runat="server">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">11kV Feeder Three Phase Supply as on
          <var id="d1">name</var></h3>
        <div class="exportimports_mainpage" id="divThreeExport" runat="server" visible="false">
          <asp:ImageButton class="PhaseExcel" ID="ThreePhaseExcel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/excel.png" OnClick="ThreePhaseExcel_Click" />
          <asp:ImageButton class="PhasePdf" ID="ThreePhasePdf" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/pdf.png" OnClick="ThreePhasePdf_Click" />
        </div>
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" id="btnThreePhase" runat="server" onserverclick="btnThreePhase_Click"><i class="fa fa-plus" id="iThree" runat="server"></i></button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-tools -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-header -->
      <div class="box-body">

        <div class="grid_table">

          <asp:GridView ID="ThreePh_Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="meterno,substation">
            <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="sno" HeaderText="S.No" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="substation" HeaderText="33kV SS" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="feedername" HeaderText="11kV Feeder" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Meter No">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <a class="iframe" href='<%#"frmFeederMasterData.aspx?meterno="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"meterno")%>'>
                    <%#Eval("meterno")%>
                  </a>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Mf" HeaderText="MF" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="rtc" HeaderText="Date" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="duration" HeaderText="Duration(Hrs:Mins)" ItemStyle-CssClass="grid_c" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_c" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="kwhcons" HeaderText="Consumption kWh" ItemStyle-CssClass="grid_rt" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_rt" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="spells" HeaderText="No.of Spells" ItemStyle-CssClass="grid_rt" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_rt" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ItemStyle-CssClass="grid_c" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_c">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <div class="actions">
                    <a class="iframe" href='<%#"frmPhaseHistory.aspx?event=Three Phase Running&meterno="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"meterno") + "&fromdate=" +  string.Format(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")) + "&todate=" + string.Format(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))%>'>
                                                                            <img src='<%=strHistoryImage%>' title="History" /></a>
                    <a class="iframe nomobile" href='<%#"frmLiveSubstation.aspx?substation="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"substation")%>'>
                                                                            <img src='<%=strGraphImage%>' title="Graph" /></a>
                  </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>

  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
<a class="iframe" href='<%#"frmFeederMasterData.aspx?meterno="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"meterno")%>'>
     <%#Eval("meterno")%>
</a>
```

is the one of it's kind. Please help me ! I'm Struggling from 3 days.

Here the Image which i want like [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPVjZ.png). But, it's opening like normal page.

Comment: You want to open the link in a new window/tab?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Esko. it needs to open like popup. I had edited my Question with image

Comment: You say the problem is it opens in another window, but then say you want it like a "popup". A "popup" often means an actual separate window/tab, or it could be just an effect created within the same page using JavaScript and CSS. Please be clear what your desired behaviour is. If this was done within the same page before using script, then the most likely explanation is the script no longer works or is not being applied to this element any more. But you haven't posted anything which would be relevant to that. So currently it's probably not possible to answer the question.

Comment: It should open in same window like what i image posted. It's working perfectly if i'm not using updatepanel. After i used it(<a>) in updatepanel the functionality was missed.

Comment: Ok, so, any script errors in your browser console when you try to open the popup?

Comment: I didn't get any error in Javascript